# Does Apple Watch support precise location in FindMy

Tags: apple-watch, find-my, airtag

I just got a new Series 9 Apple Watch. I was under the impression that it supported the precise location feature in the "Find My" app, both for AirTags, and for iPhone 15's.

I can't get it to find one of my AirTags at all. It shows "with you" when it's very close, but the "Play sound" button says "Item unreachable."

Another air tag will play a sound, but it gives me **useless** map directions that would have me drive around my neighborhood and back to my house.

My shiny new iPhone 15 pro will show an arrow on the screen pointing towards either of my AirTags, and a pretty accurate distance measure, making it easy to hunt something down.

Should my new Series 9 Apple Watch support "Precise location", and be able to show the same directional arrow that my iPhone 15 will, showing direction and range to one of my AirTags or to my iPhone 15 pro.?